# Configuring/Installing log4net for RavenDB in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, ravendb

I'm trying to configure my C# project to use [log4net for RavenDB](http://nuget.org/packages/log4net.Raven).  I already have log4net working with a FileAppender, but the RavenAppender doesn't seem to be working right now.  The following are the steps I have taken so far:

#### Step 1: Installing log4net.Raven

I installed the log4net.Raven library using the following NuGet Package Manager console instructions (taken from the package website linked to above):

```
Install-Package log4net.Raven
```

That command added the log4net.Raven library to my project references.

#### Step 2: Configuring Web.config

In my Web.config file, I have the following settings, most of which are copy and pasted from the README file for the [log4net.Raven project on GitHub](https://github.com/antonsamarsky/log4net.Raven/blob/master/README) (the owner of log4net.Raven also has similar [configuration settings published on his blog](http://samarskyy.blogspot.com/2011/10/log4net-appender-for-raven-db.html)):

```xml
<!-- Example connection string config from blog -->
<configsections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net">
</configsections>
<connectionstrings>
  <add connectionstring="Url=http://raven; DefaultDatabase=Log" name="RavenLogs">
    <add connectionstring="Url=http://localhost:8080;user=asa;password=asa" name="SecureRaven">
    </add>
  </add>
</connectionstrings>

<!-- My current config -->
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="RavenDB" connectionString="Url=http://localhost:8080;Database=MyDatabase" />
</connectionStrings>

<!-- Example log4net config from README.
My project uses these settings except for the connectionString value,
which is set to "RavenDB" to match the setting name above.
-->
<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <!-- LogFileAppender settings here -->
    </appender>
    <appender name="RavenAppender" type="log4net.Raven.RavenAppender">
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <levelMin value="INFO" />
            <levelMax value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
        <connectionString value="RavenDB"/>
        <maxNumberOfRequestsPerSession value="100"/>
        <bufferSize value="50" />
        <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
            <threshold value="ERROR" />
        </evaluator>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="RavenAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

#### Step 3: Logging from C# code

In my C# code, I have the following:

```cs
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private static ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(FooController));

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        _log.Info("Hello World!");
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

That code will write out to a log file on my workstation, so from that I know that log4net in general is working correctly.  But for RavenDB, I've been checking the Documents and Logs for MyDatabase through the Raven studio in a web browser, and I do not see any Info level log with the message "Hello World".

Does anyone have any ideas of what the problem could be and how to fix it?

Comment: do you have any code where you are actually instantiating the Log4Net object..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I added more code showing what I have in my project.  The logging is working with the FileAppender, so I'm assuming my C# code is correct, and that it's just my RavenAppender configuration that's giving me problems.

Comment: Can you change the error level to perhaps log everything.. it's probably something simple or somewhere in the code where you are logging to the RavenDB perhaps you are setting a log level that's not in the .config you have setup

Comment: @DJKRAZE I checked my C# code, and I'm not setting the log level programmatically anywhere in it.  I also tried commenting out the `filter` node in the config file, and then also the `evaluator` node, but still no luck.

Comment: I would go one further .. try a complete reboot.. I know it sounds strange but I have seen stranger things happen

Comment: @DJKRAZE Still no luck, but they were all good suggestions though, thank you.

Comment: no problem.. I wonder just as one more try perhaps you could create another instance of the _log and see what happens.. I had that happen before and I can't remember for the life of me remember how I corrected it..

Comment: Your RavenAppender says the connection string name is RavenLogs, yet your config has the connection string name of RavenDb. Is this just a typo?

Comment: @ChrisSainty my project is using "RavenDB", "RavenLogs" is what comes from the example config.  I updated the config lines above to show what's actually in my project.

Comment: @ColdHawaiian question: any reason why you're using Log4Net instead of NLog ? If you're interested, we can post some NLog examples.

Comment: @Pure.Krome I'm using Log4Net in my project because that's what the rest of my team's codebase is already using.

Answer (score 1):

May be the problem is here:

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
```

if you don't have class named FileAppender in your project you need to add the library name where FileAppender is, for example:

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender"
          type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender, log4net.Raven">
```

(the syntax for type is `=" Fully qualified class name , assembly file name , version , culture , public key token "`)

Answer (score 0):

Try debug log4net as here [Log4Net Troubleshooting](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx)
If you find this line:

```
log4net: Adding appender named [RavenAppender] to logger [root].
```

RavenAppender is working